# Application-defined or object-defined error on AdvancedFilter macro

Tags: excel, vba

I've put together this macro using bits of code from online, and managed to get it to work on a test workbook, but it since transferring it to PERSONAL it keeps coming up with different errors. I've managed to fix a few but am now stuck on getting a "1004 - application-defined or object-defined error" on this line:

```
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = x.Value
```

The macro seems to run ok up to this point, generating two new worksheets with the filtered data, but then it stops at Sheet3, which it leaves blank and doesn't give a name.

If anyone could explain where I'm going wrong here that would be much appreciated, as I'm still learning!

Thanks :)

```
Sub NAVExportStarter()


Dim NAVExport As Workbook
Set NAVExport = ActiveWorkbook



'Filter and Copy to New Sheets
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim x As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim last As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet

'specify sheet name in which the data is stored
Set sht = NAVExport.Sheets("249")

'change filter column in the following code
last = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sht.Range("A1:O" & last)


sht.Range("C1:C" & last).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("AA1"), Unique:=True

For Each x In Range([AA2], Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp))
With rng
.AutoFilter
.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=x.Value
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = x.Value
ActiveSheet.Paste
End With
Next x

' Turn off filter
sht.AutoFilterMode = False

With Application
.CutCopyMode = False
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With




' Roman Imperial
Dim NAVImperial As Worksheet
Dim LIVEImperial As Workbook
Dim LIVEImperialSheet As Worksheet

Dim UniqueIDs As Range
Dim Descriptions As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set NAVExport = ThisWorkbook
Set LIVEImperial = Workbooks.Open("\\WDMYCLOUDEX2\Public\Sortcoding\Roman Imperial.xlsm")
Set NAVImperial = NAVExport.Sheets("ROMAN IMPERIAL")
Set LIVEImperialSheet = LIVEImperial.Sheets("LIVE Data")

With NAVImperial
  LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set UniqueIDs = NAVImperial.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
Set Descriptions = NAVImperial.Range("F2:F" & LastRow)

UniqueIDs.Copy
LIVEImperialSheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Descriptions.Copy
LIVEImperialSheet.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

LIVEImperialSheet.Range("C2:O" & LastRow).FillDown

LIVEImperial.Close True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Greek
Dim NAVGreek As Worksheet
Dim LIVEGreek As Workbook
Dim LIVEGreekSheet As Worksheet

Dim UniqueIDG As Range
Dim DescriptionsG As Range
Dim LastRowG As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set LIVEGreek = Workbooks.Open("\\WDMYCLOUDEX2\Public\Sortcoding\Greek.xlsx")
Set NAVGreek = NAVExport.Sheets("GREEK")
Set LIVEGreekSheet = LIVEGreek.Sheets("LIVE Data")

With NAVGreek
  LastRowG = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set UniqueIDG = NAVGreek.Range("B2:B" & LastRowG)
Set DescriptionsG = NAVGreek.Range("F2:F" & LastRowG)

UniqueIDG.Copy
LIVEGreekSheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
DescriptionsG.Copy
LIVEGreekSheet.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

LIVEGreekSheet.Range("C2:R" & LastRowG).FillDown
LIVEGreek.Close True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


'Roman Provincial
Dim NAVProvincial As Worksheet
Dim LIVEProvincial As Workbook
Dim LIVEProvincialSheet As Worksheet

Dim UniqueIDP As Range
Dim DescriptionsP As Range
Dim LastRowP As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set LIVEProvincial = Workbooks.Open("\\WDMYCLOUDEX2\Public\Sortcoding\Roman Provincial.xlsx")
Set NAVProvincial = NAVExport.Sheets("ROMAN PROVINCIAL")
Set LIVEProvincialSheet = LIVEProvincial.Sheets("LIVE Data")

With NAVProvincial
  LastRowP = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set UniqueIDP = NAVProvincial.Range("B2:B" & LastRowP)
Set DescriptionsP = NAVProvincial.Range("F2:F" & LastRowP)

UniqueIDP.Copy
LIVEProvincialSheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
DescriptionsP.Copy
LIVEProvincialSheet.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

LIVEProvincialSheet.Range("C2:G" & LastRowP).FillDown
LIVEProvincial.Close True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


'Republican
Dim NAVRepublican As Worksheet
Dim LIVERepublican As Workbook
Dim LIVERepublicanSheet As Worksheet

Dim UniqueIDR As Range
Dim DescriptionsR As Range
Dim LastRowR As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set LIVERepublican = Workbooks.Open("\\WDMYCLOUDEX2\Public\Sortcoding\Roman Republican.xlsx")
Set NAVRepublican = NAVExport.Sheets("ROMAN REPUBLIC")
Set LIVERepublicanSheet = LIVERepublican.Sheets("LIVE Data")

With NAVRepublican
  LastRowR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set UniqueIDR = NAVRepublican.Range("B2:B" & LastRowR)
Set DescriptionsR = NAVRepublican.Range("F2:F" & LastRowR)

UniqueIDR.Copy
LIVERepublicanSheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
DescriptionsR.Copy
LIVERepublicanSheet.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

LIVERepublicanSheet.Range("C" & LastRowR).FillDown
LIVERepublican.Close True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Imperatorial
Dim NAVImperatorial As Worksheet
Dim LIVEImperatorial As Workbook
Dim LIVEImperatorialSheet As Worksheet

Dim UniqueIDI As Range
Dim DescriptionsI As Range
Dim LastRowI As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set LIVEImperatorial = Workbooks.Open("\\WDMYCLOUDEX2\Public\Sortcoding\Roman Imperatorial.xlsx")
Set NAVImperatorial = NAVExport.Sheets("ROMAN IMPERATORIAL")
Set LIVEImperatorialSheet = LIVEImperatorial.Sheets("LIVE Data")

With NAVImperatorial
  LastRowI = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set UniqueIDI = NAVImperatorial.Range("B2:B" & LastRowI)
Set DescriptionsI = NAVImperatorial.Range("F2:F" & LastRowI)

UniqueIDI.Copy
LIVEImperatorialSheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
DescriptionsI.Copy
LIVEImperatorialSheet.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

LIVEImperatorialSheet.Range("C" & LastRowI).FillDown
LIVEImperatorial.Close True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Byzantine
Dim NAVByzantine As Worksheet
Dim LIVEByzantine As Workbook
Dim LIVEByzantineSheet As Worksheet

Dim UniqueIDB As Range
Dim DescriptionsB As Range
Dim LastRowB As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set LIVEByzantine = Workbooks.Open("\\WDMYCLOUDEX2\Public\Sortcoding\Byzantine.xlsx")
Set NAVByzantine = NAVExport.Sheets("BYZANTINE")
Set LIVEByzantineSheet = LIVEByzantine.Sheets("LIVE Data")

With NAVByzantine
  LastRowB = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set UniqueIDB = NAVByzantine.Range("B2:B" & LastRowB)
Set DescriptionsB = NAVByzantine.Range("F2:F" & LastRowB)

UniqueIDB.Copy
LIVEByzantineSheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
DescriptionsB.Copy
LIVEByzantineSheet.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

LIVEByzantineSheet.Range("C2:E" & LastRowB).FillDown
LIVEByzantine.Close True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'World
Dim NAVWorld As Worksheet
Dim LIVEWorld As Workbook
Dim LIVEWorldSheet As Worksheet

Dim UniqueIDW As Range
Dim DescriptionsW As Range
Dim LastRowW As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set LIVEWorld = Workbooks.Open("\\WDMYCLOUDEX2\Public\Sortcoding\World.xlsx")
Set NAVWorld = NAVExport.Sheets("WORLD")
Set LIVEWorldSheet = LIVEWorld.Sheets("LIVE Data")

With NAVWorld
  LastRowW = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set UniqueIDW = NAVWorld.Range("B2:B" & LastRowW)
Set DescriptionsW = NAVWorld.Range("F2:F" & LastRowW)

UniqueIDW.Copy
LIVEWorldSheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
DescriptionsW.Copy
LIVEWorldSheet.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

LIVEWorldSheet.Range("C2:E" & LastRowW).FillDown
LIVEWorld.Close True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the value of `x` when it fails? Is it a valid sheet name? (I suspect not)

Comment: What value does `x` cell have when stopped on error? Please, move the cursor over `x.Value`...

Comment: `Range("AA1")`, `Range([AA2], Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp))` and `Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))` are and/or contain unqualified references i.e. it is unknown which worksheet or workbook (last case) they belong to.  `[AA2]` is ridiculous since simply the quoted string `"AA2"` can be used. Try something like `sht.Range("AA1")`, `sht.Range("AA2", sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp))` and `NavExport.Sheets.Add(After:=NavExport.Sheets(NavExport.Sheets.Count))`.